# Azure web app to serve vuejs app

Tags: node.js, webpack, azure-web-app-service, vue.js

I have a vuejs app using webpack, which can also be package into electron app.

The structure of the app is like the following:

https://github.com/kahwooi/vuetron

It can be run on `webpack-dev-server`.

My question is can the app run on Azure or any web server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, generally speaking, Azure Web Apps as a web service platform provides production environment for web applications. So you can try the following steps for the simplest requirement to run `vuetron` on Azure.

1. Install the vuetron on your local environment:

   ```
   # Install electron and webpack-dev-server 
   npm install -g electron webpack-dev-server

   # Install vue-cli and scaffold boilerplate
   npm install -g vue-cli
   vue init kahwooi/vuetron my-project

   # Install dependencies and run your app in development mode
   cd my-project
   npm install
   # View app using browser at http://localhost:8080, automatically updates the browser on changes.

   # Run as electron desktop app
   webpack
   ```
2. Remove the `/dist` in `.gitignore` file in your directory.
3. Create a Web App with local git deployment via Azure-Cli:

   ```
   azure login
   azure config mode asm
   azure site create --git {your_site_name}
   ```
4. Deploy your application to Azure via Git:

   ```
   git add .
   git commit -m "{your commit message}"
   git push azure master
   ```
5. Finally, launch your live Azure app in the browser:

   ```
   azure site browse
   ```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: "scripts": {
    "prod": "webpack --progress --config build/webpack.prod.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run prod"
  }. This is a part of my package.json. When I deploy my app to Azure, I get error "webpack: not found". Looks like missing package. How can I restore packages in azure app service

Comment: Per my experience, you can try to change the `webpack` to `node_modules/.bin/webpack` or `node_modules/.bin/webpack.cmd`

Comment: Do I have to checkin node_modules to the repository which I am deploying? I don't want to. Is there any way using which, I can restore packages before running build?

Comment: If you leverage the local git to deploy your project to Azure, the deployment will automatic install the packages depending on your `package.json` file.

Comment: That's amazing... I'm stuck on those simple question for a lot of time.. No guides and No tutorials summarized the steps easy as you did here! =]